# pip install package - failed with error code 1/2

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

I'm having issues installing `pygrib` using `pip`. I tried installing `pygrib` by using `easy_install`, and I get a similar error.

Using `pip` I get this error:

```
Command "C:\Users\Brandon\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Brandon\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-veulay9n\\pygrib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Brandon\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ff_s5247-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Brandon\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-veulay9n\pygrib\
```

Using `easy_install` I get this error:

```
c:\users\brandon\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\edm\envs\user\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(12) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
    pygrib.c(242): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'grib_api.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

In fact, `pygrib` is the only package that doesn't work when I try `pip` or `easy_install` - it works for any package I try to install. What's going on here and how do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pygrib` is a Python wrapper for `libgrib-api`. To compile `pygrib` you need to compile `libgrib-abi` and install the library and the header files. Download sources from https://software.ecmwf.int/wiki/display/GRIB/Releases.

Comment: Note that [Windows support is experimental](https://software.ecmwf.int/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=48109524), and although it doesn’t look that complicated if you know what you’re doing, the instructions aren’t very helpful if you aren’t that familiar with compiling C code or setting environment variables in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

`pygrib` includes one or more Python extension modules written in C which need to be compiled as part of the installation, and this C code depends upon some library that provides a header file named "`grib_api.h`".  Find and install that C library, and `pygrib` installation should then work.